# sql aggregation function using

Tags: sql, aggregation

There are several tables in DB:

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, price, screen)
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
```

and I need to find

Find the model number of the product (PC, laptop, or printer) with the highest price.
Result set: model.

I managed to write the following query:

```
select model from 
(select model, price from PC
union
select model, price from Laptop
union
select model, price from Printer) G
```

and now I need to plot the model/models from set G, wich have a max price

I can easily select a max price by adding to select clause -  max(G.price),
but i need models and only models...

what syntax would be right?

thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`?

Comment: What SQL product is this?

Comment: it's just a standart SQL, pl/sql also can be used

Comment: @tania Since it seems you are having a hard time getting the correct answer, can you post some sample data for each table and the the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Highest price only?

```
select model
from
(select 
   model, 
   rank() over (order by max(price) desc) as [rank] 
from 
  (select model, price from PC
   union
   select model, price from Laptop
   union
   select model, price from Printer) u
   group by model) g
where g.rank = 1
```

I'm sorry, but I'm currently not able to test if we can use MAX() inside of a rank(). If not, add another sub query. First determine the max(price), then the rank.

So, MAX() inside of RANK() is working...
An alternative, with a simple syntax:

```
select top 1 with ties 
  g.model
from
(select 
   u.model, 
   max(u.price) as [maxPrice] 
from 
  (select model, price from PC
   union
   select model, price from Laptop
   union
   select model, price from Printer) u
   group by model) g
order by g.maxPrice desc
```

- edit 1: added 'top 1' since only a single record is expected
- edit 2: removed 'top 1', added rank
- edit 3: removed 'partition by model', after using sqlfiddle. Thanks @bluefeet!
- edit 4: added alternative 'with ties'. Again, thanks to @bluefeet.

Comment: it returns the whole bunch of the models in a db... not just one with the highest price

Comment: Sorry, thought you needed all highest prices, I will add 'top 1'.

Comment: with ONE highest price :) there might be ties between models, so there might be from one to many returns, but with the same(one) max price...

Comment: Okay, sorry didn't think of that one. Answer will be updated.

Comment: @Jacco FYI on the `TOP 1` just add `WITH TIES` and it will return multiple

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks a lot! Didn't even know of it's existence... Have to dive into that one, once I can access SSMS again.

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution which works..

SELECT model
FROM pc
WHERE price >= ALL(SELECT MAX(price) FROM pc UNION SELECT MAX(price) FROM laptop UNION SELECT MAX(price) FROM printer)

UNION

SELECT model
FROM laptop
WHERE price >= ALL(SELECT MAX(price) FROM pc UNION SELECT MAX(price) FROM laptop UNION SELECT MAX(price) FROM printer)

UNION

SELECT model
FROM printer
WHERE price >= ALL(SELECT MAX(price) FROM pc UNION SELECT MAX(price) FROM laptop UNION SELECT MAX(price) FROM printer)

Comment: Yes, this works.  It would be even more efficient with `UNION ALL` in place of `UNION` each time it occurs.  Also, you don't need the `MAX` in the subselects, because of the `>= ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Jacco's answer,

```
select model
from
(select model, max(price) as maxPrice 
from 
  (select model, price from PC
   union
   select model, price from Laptop
   union
   select model, price from Printer) u
   group by model) g
where maxPrice = max(maxPrice)
```

change to limit 1 instead of mysql.

Comment: not really... An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    model
FROM 
    (
    SELECT model, price, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY price DESC) AS seq FROM PC
    UNION
    SELECT model, price, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY price DESC) AS seq FROM Laptop
    UNION
    SELECT model, price, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY price DESC) AS seq FROM Printer
) final
WHERE
    seq = 1
```

Comment: dont' quite understand what are you doing in this query, but it returns, the highest prices within each type, eg model with highest price for printer, model with highest price for Laptop and for PC,

Comment: and should return just one model/many models with highest price (only one price is the highest)in the whole DB, o

Comment: @tania - If that is what you are trying to do, then why doesn't Ulises answer work for you??

Comment: @tania - You just want the model (and only the model) of the product with the highest price, correct?